# Bulk Insert/Delete EF6 entities configured with MapToStoredProcedures without duplicating stored procedure definiton

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, bulkinsert

I have an existing Entity Framework (6) context model with Entities setup mapping to an existing Sql Server database. Several entities with composite keys are setup to call stored procedures as replacements for standard insert/update/delete statements using the Fluent API as described in: [Code First Insert/Update/Delete Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx)

A simplified example building off the examples on that page:

```
modelBuilder  
  .Entity<BlogPost>()  
  .MapToStoredProcedures(s =>  
    s.Update(u => u.HasName("modify_blogpost")
                   .Parameter(b => b.BlogId, "blog_id")
                   .Parameter(b => b.PostId, "post_id")
                   .Parameter(b => b.Content, "content")
     .Delete(d => d.HasName("delete_blogpost")
                   .Parameter(b => b.BlogId, "blog_id")
                   .Parameter(b => b.PostId, "post_id")
     .Insert(i => i.HasName("insert_blogpost")
                   .Parameter(b => b.BlogId, "blog_id")
                   .Parameter(b => b.Content, "content")
                   .Result(b => b.PostId, "generated_post_identity")));
```

(Note that I don't have control over the table/procedure structure, and the stored procedures do several things beyond just the normal insert/update/delete statements)

There are cases where I have to call insert or delete for 100s to 1000s of records at a time, and would like to "batch" such operations to improve the performance.

I know multiple ways to batch the stored procedure calls directly (e.g. ADO.Net, StringBuilder into a single text blob, etc), but all of the methods I can come up with would require duplicating the stored procedure name/parameters/arguments in another location. Which is what I'd like to avoid **if possible**.

I tried [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended), but it does not work for this case and seems to have become inactive (as of July 13 2016 the last commit is about 1 year old with 127 open issues). It does not check for a MapToStoredProcedures configuration so it directly builds delete/update statements in a text command blob for its batching purposes. And in my case the database constraints/permissions will cause that to throw Exceptions.

Is there a library/framework/plugin that *does* follow the MapToStoredProcedures configuration for bulk actions? Or perhaps a way to use Reflection or some other tricks to build batched inserts/deletes without having to replicate the stored procedure mapping somewhere else in code?

Comment: Have you looked at [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) yet?

Comment: That appears to be built using [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx). Which still won't utilize the existing stored procedure mappings. I really **really** need to use the existing stored procedures to do the inserts/deletes, so to get EntityFramework.BulkInsert (or SqlBulkCopy) to handle inserts/deletes in this case may require an additional 1-2 stored procedures (perhaps with a table-value parameter) to perform the needed stored proc calls based on what was "BulkInserted" to a temp table or table-value parameter, etc